# Margins on children of ConstraintLayout do not display?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm using Android's new ConstraintLayout for my app and I've been having problems having margins on elements show up. For reference I'm using the following line in my gradle file for ConstraintLayout `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4`. The code in my layout is below.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/post_vertical_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/post_vertical_padding"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TitleText"
        android:id="@+id/post_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/post_line_vertical_padding"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/post_type_horizontal_padding"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/post_type_horizontal_padding"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/poster_profile_pic"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/poster_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/post_type"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/post_type" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. If you use `paddingStart`, no need for `paddingLeft`
2. `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/poster_profile_pic"`
   there is no image view here with id `poster_profile_pic`
3. `android:layout_marginBottom`
   will not work unless you include `constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
4. `android:layout_marginRight` should be `android:layout_marginLeft` but in `poster_name` because `poster_name` has `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/post_type"`

Comment: Hi amorenew. The problems you posted are correct based on the code snippet, but don't exist in the actual code. That's my fault for trying to isolate one instance removing my surrounding code. Your 3rd point, however, was helpful. It seems for a margin to be applied in a `ConstraintLayout` there must be a constraint in that direction. So a left margin will only be applied if there is a constraint for the left side on that element. This does not include constraints from other elements on that side, such as a `layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf` which would not work.